# Vertically align text with different font sizes

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-align

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/8bnLkyLv/

```
    <div class="alert">
        <p><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>This is some text</p>
    </div>
```

It's super simple, `<p>` tag that contains a `<i>` tag that containers a font awesome icon.

The `<i>` tag needs to be bigger than the text.

I need the text and the icon to be centered horizontally in the red container.

I know I could to it by absolutely positioning the `<i>` tag but that seems like a lot of messing for something so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give the *bigger* inline-level element - the `<i>` element in this case - a [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) of `middle`.

```css
.alert { background: red; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center; }

.alert p {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.alert p i {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle; /* <-- Added declaration */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert">
    <p>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        This is some text
    </p>
</div>
```